# How to Mask specific region of the image and create a black background image with masked portion as white color

Tags: java, android, kotlin, shapes, mask

I'm having an image view. I have to create a mask with white color and the non masked portion should be black color and save it as an bitmap or jpg.

Original Image
[image: Original Image]

Masked Image (Needs to create like this)
[image: mask image]

From the above original image I have to mask the dog and create it as a bitmap or png

Comment: I'm puzzled. You appear to be asking how to do something, but showing us that it was done. What am I missing?

Comment: No, The above mentioned is the final output required. I need to do the above mentioned programmatically. @OldDogProgrammer

Comment: So, how was the mask created?

Comment: @OldDogProgrammer It was actually created in photoshop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make a custom view which support draw line, make custom view background be transparent. Then put that view on top the ImageView in your layout. And after drawed the mask, just save the drawing bitmap create from custom view.

Comment: Thanks, but if I create a transparent background how can I change the background to black color

Comment: Nice! Good job bro @GeorgeGlyn